# Save data from VBA userform into to two sheets

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to save data entered in a userform into to differnet sheets.

The problem I'm currently having is that, one of the sheets VBA has to look up the specific row where it sould be added, but the other sheet is going to be a history of the data inserted, so it needs to insert the data on the next free row.

I have this code which works for looking up and inserting into the first sheet:

```
Private Sub pSave()

Dim rw As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Hardware")

    'Takting the inserted values from the userform and inserting them into the spreadsheet

        totRows = Worksheets("Hardware").Range("A4").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

        For i = 2 To totRows
            If Trim(Worksheets("Hardware").Cells(i, 1)) = Trim(ComboBox_PCNameChoose.Value) Then
            'Inserting them into the Hardware sheet (The main sheet)
                Worksheets("Hardware").Cells(i, 12).Value = TextBox_Name.Text
                Worksheets("Hardware").Cells(i, 13).Value = TextBox_Email.Text
                Worksheets("Hardware").Cells(i, 14).Value = TextBox_PhoneNumber.Text
                Worksheets("Hardware").Cells(i, 15).Value = DTPicker_Borrow.Value
                Worksheets("Hardware").Cells(i, 16).Value = DTPicker_Return.Value

            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
```

I know this works in another userform for inserting data into the next free row, but I cant figure out how to get it to work when saving in two sheets at the same time

```
Dim rw As Integer
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws2 = Worksheets("Rental_History")
If rw = ws2.Cells.Find(What:="*", Searchorder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=Previous, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1 Then
    ws2.Cells(rw, 10).Value = TextBox_Name.Text
    ws2.Cells(rw, 11).Value = TextBox_Email.Text
    ws2.Cells(rw, 12).Value = TextBox_PhoneNumber.Text
    ws2.Cells(rw, 13).Value = DTPicker_Borrow.Value
    ws2.Cells(rw, 14).Value = DTPicker_Return.Value
End If
```

In Advance, thank you for your time and help! :)

Best Regards 
- Kira

Comment: What happens when you are running this code ? Put a break point in the second part of the code and check rw , what does it hold ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will achieve what you expect, instead of using a For Loop to find the row where you want to add the first bit of data I used the .Find method, as this would be faster, instead of looping through every row until you find a match, the find method would quickly jump to the matched row.

Also it is important to note that I changed the declaration of rw from Integer to Long, as there are more cells in Excel than an Integer variable can handle:

```
Private Sub pSave()
Dim rw As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Hardware")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Worksheets("Rental_History")
Dim foundval As Range

'Taking the inserted values from the userform and inserting them into the spreadsheet
Set foundval = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Trim(ComboBox_PCNameChoose.Value)) 'find the value that matches
If Not foundval Is Nothing Then 'if found, use that row to insert data
    'Inserting them into the Hardware sheet (The main sheet)
    ws.Cells(foundval.Row, 12).Value = TextBox_Name.Text
    ws.Cells(foundval.Row, 13).Value = TextBox_Email.Text
    ws.Cells(foundval.Row, 14).Value = TextBox_PhoneNumber.Text
    ws.Cells(foundval.Row, 15).Value = DTPicker_Borrow.Value
    ws.Cells(foundval.Row, 16).Value = DTPicker_Return.Value
End If

rw = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
'get the next free row
ws2.Cells(rw, 10).Value = TextBox_Name.Text
ws2.Cells(rw, 11).Value = TextBox_Email.Text
ws2.Cells(rw, 12).Value = TextBox_PhoneNumber.Text
ws2.Cells(rw, 13).Value = DTPicker_Borrow.Value
ws2.Cells(rw, 14).Value = DTPicker_Return.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly, and thanks for the advice, I'll keep it in mind when I'm going to start my next project :) 

Thank you so much Xabier :)

Comment: @Kira glad I could help... :)

Comment: I have just foundt one problem though, I can't set my rowsource for the combobox, which i do through creating a Name in the sheet (formulas -> create from section), here i usually put in the following code: =OFFSET(Hardware!#REF!;0;0;COUNTA(Hardware!$A:$A);1)

But when i do this the userform wont accept the name "PC_Name" as a rowsource?

Comment: @KiraJensen are you sure your formula `=OFFSET...` is correct as the **#REF** should probably not be there? It should probably be something like `=OFFSET(Hardware!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Hardware!$A:$A),COUNTA($1:$1))`

Comment: i have a problem getting it to work now? When i push the button it doesn't send the data to ws only to ws2? Its like it doesn't read the code correctly? Any clue to why this is happening? :)

Comment: Do you have `Trim(ComboBox_PCNameChoose.Value)` in Column A of ws as a whole value? Its probably easier if you were to step through the code by pressing F8 and checking the values as you go through the code and see what is being caught and what isn't...

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rw As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Hardware")
Dim rw1 As Integer
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Rental_History")

'Takting the inserted values from the userform and inserting them into the spreadsheet

    totRows = Worksheets("Hardware").Range("A4").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    For i = 2 To totRows
        If Trim(Worksheets("Hardware").Cells(i, 1)) = Trim(ComboBox_PCNameChoose.Value) Then
        'Inserting them into the Hardware sheet (The main sheet)
            rw = ws2.Cells.Find(What:="*", Searchorder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=Previous, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1 'updates rw  as it changes at each loop
            ws.Cells(i, 12).Value = TextBox_Name.Text
            ws2.Cells(rw, 10).Value = ws.Cells(i, 12).Value
            ws.Cells(i, 13).Value = TextBox_Email.Text
            ws2.Cells(rw, 11).Value = ws.Cells(i, 13).Value
            ws.Cells(i, 14).Value = TextBox_PhoneNumber.Text
            ws2.Cells(rw, 12).Value = ws.Cells(i, 14).Value
            ws.Cells(i, 15).Value = DTPicker_Borrow.Value
            ws2.Cells(rw, 13).Value = ws.Cells(i, 15).Value
            ws.Cells(i, 16).Value = DTPicker_Return.Value
            ws2.Cells(rw, 14).Value = ws.Cells(i, 16).Value
       End If
   Next i
```

Comment: You declared `rw1` but never used it, you declare it as an Integer when there are more rows in excel than an Integer can handle... also using a For Loop to insert data is inefficient as the row that actually matches the criteria could be the last one, and as such the code is checking every single row until it gets there... Apart from that this would also work. :)

Comment: you are right @Xabier, my mistake. I just answered quickly while my own Excel was running :) rw1 is of no use here

Comment: ´Thank you for your response Cyril! :)

Comment: Anytime @Kira Jensen Hope it helps a bit